# Can CockroachDB primary keys fall out of sync?

Tags: cockroachdb

I know that in PostgreSQL, if you use automatically generated primary keys, they can fall out of sync (which prevents you from inserting new rows because the automatically generated ID is already present in the primary key).

Is this a problem in CockroachDB? I'd imagine it could be because it’s distributed and there’s no simple way to check for existing values used in the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, CockroachDB doesn’t run into this problem with its automatically generated primary keys (known as [SERIAL](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/serial.html)). It accomplishes this by generating an integer using both the timestamp and an ID of the node executing the insert. This combination is likely to be globally unique except in extreme cases.

Because this value is unique (except in incredibly rare cases), you don’t have to worry about an insert being rejected due to the automatically generated primary key. It also can't get stuck, since a new value is generated on each attempt.

A side note: generating `SERIAL` values also executes more quickly than something like `AUTO INCREMENT` in a distributed system because it doesn’t require nodes to coordinate with one another.